# Best way to find (a) buggy file(s) with git

Tags: git, debugging

I wonder if any of you have a good method finding the "bad file/code".
Let's say we have a branch from a working master. I change several files (+10).
After the change I discover that something broke, and let's for arguments sake state it is not an obvious error.
When stashing my changes - it works.
Popping the back the changes - broken.

I know I can use git diff, which is excellent, but that means I have to understand all the implications of a specific change (and in a legacy system you didn't build that is more often then not the case). And for 10+ files it tend to get boooring - and we don't want boring, do we?

I was pondering about a way to stash only specific files - is that possible?

Or perhaps to make a copy of the branch and "checkout --" the files one by one?

How would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a way to test if a given revision is good or not, then you can use `git-bisect` to find the bad commit. See [the part "Binary Search" of the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search).

Comment: Yes, but here `HEAD` is good; unstashed changes are bad. The error is in the changes. There's nothing to bisect.

Comment: Commit all files one by one, then bisect. Better yet - split the existing uncommitted changes into separate commits, then bisect.

Comment: Thank you for your combined effort! Didn't know you could commit changes separately [break-up-changes-into-different-commits](http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2008/10/31/break-up-changes-into-different-commits-with-git-add-p/). For paranoid reasons I will do this from a branch copy.